# RDD to LabeledPoint conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

If I have a RDD with about 500 columns and 200 million rows, and `RDD.columns.indexOf("target", 0)` shows `Int = 77` which tells me my targeted dependent variable is at column number 77. But I don't have enough knowledge on how to select desired (partial) columns as features (say I want columns from 23 to 59, 111 to 357, 399 to 489). I am wondering if I can apply such:

```
val data = rdd.map(col => new LabeledPoint(
    col(77).toDouble, Vectors.dense(??.map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
```

Any suggestions or guidance will be much appreciated.

Maybe I messed up RDD with DataFrame, I can convert the RDD to DataFrame with `.toDF()` or it is easier to accomplish the goal with DataFrame than RDD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume your data looks more or less like this:

```scala
import scala.util.Random.{setSeed, nextDouble}
setSeed(1)

case class Record(
    foo: Double, target: Double, x1: Double, x2: Double, x3: Double)

val rows = sc.parallelize(
    (1 to 10).map(_ => Record(
        nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble
   ))
)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows)
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("""
  SELECT ROUND(foo, 2) foo,
         ROUND(target, 2) target,
         ROUND(x1, 2) x1,
         ROUND(x2, 2) x2,
         ROUND(x2, 2) x3 
  FROM df""").show
```

So we have data as below:

```
+----+------+----+----+----+
| foo|target|  x1|  x2|  x3|
+----+------+----+----+----+
|0.73|  0.41|0.21|0.33|0.33|
|0.01|  0.96|0.94|0.95|0.95|
| 0.4|  0.35|0.29|0.51|0.51|
|0.77|  0.66|0.16|0.38|0.38|
|0.69|  0.81|0.01|0.52|0.52|
|0.14|  0.48|0.54|0.58|0.58|
|0.62|  0.18|0.01|0.16|0.16|
|0.54|  0.97|0.25|0.39|0.39|
|0.43|  0.23|0.89|0.04|0.04|
|0.66|  0.12|0.65|0.98|0.98|
+----+------+----+----+----+
```

and we want to ignore `foo` and `x2` and extract `LabeledPoint(target, Array(x1, x3))`:

```scala
// Map feature names to indices
val featInd = List("x1", "x3").map(df.columns.indexOf(_))

// Or if you want to exclude columns
val ignored = List("foo", "target", "x2")
val featInd = df.columns.diff(ignored).map(df.columns.indexOf(_))

// Get index of target
val targetInd = df.columns.indexOf("target") 

df.rdd.map(r => LabeledPoint(
   r.getDouble(targetInd), // Get target value
   // Map feature indices to values
   Vectors.dense(featInd.map(r.getDouble(_)).toArray) 
))
```

Comment: Great code! and it works very well. I just did some small modification for the typo `val targetInd = df.columns.indexOf("target")`

Comment: appreciate indeed. Is there a quick way to de-list the feature in your example? Say you have `val featInd = List("x1", "x3).map....`, what if I have 200 features I want and only supress 3 of them? Something like `val featInd = De-List("x2").map....`?

Comment: Sure, you can use `filter` or `diff`. I've added an example.

Comment: You are superb!! diff() it is!

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I add one more question...  what if the original rdd is via JDBC, and all are in Decimal data type? It seems the LabledPoint only takes Double. Any quick way to convert the columns from Decimal to Double?

Comment: These are `java.math.BigDecimal` not `scala.math.BigDecimal`, right? If so you can replace `r.getDouble(_)` with `r.getDecimal(_).floatValue.toDouble`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84334/discussion-between-richard-liu-and-zero323).

Comment: I have an existing DF that is all string fields. Of course, I get errors in the labeledpoint conversion.  I need to change that line to convert from strings into the vector of features. Should I just cast all the fields first or is there a way to add that?

Comment: Any way to convert r.getDouble(_) to something like `r.getDouble(_)>0 ? 1:0`  This is prob closer to java but you get the point.