# Permutations of Models in Spark mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark 1.6.1 with Scala 2.10.5 built in. I am building a set of permutation models using binary numbers but I've now hit a wall for a few days now. Here is the code (partially taken from zero323 at [RDD to LabeledPoint conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638770/rdd-to-labeledpoint-conversion)):

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

import scala.util.Random.{setSeed, nextDouble}
setSeed(123)

case class Record(
target: Double, x1: Double, x2: Double, x3: Double, x4:Double, x5:Double, x6:Double)

val rows = sc.parallelize(
(1 to 50).map(_ => Record(
    nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextDouble)))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows)
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT ROUND(target, 2) target,
ROUND(x1, 2) x1,
ROUND(x2, 2) x2,
ROUND(x3, 2) x3,
ROUND(x4, 2) x4,
ROUND(x5, 2) x5,
ROUND(x6, 2) x6
FROM df""").show
```

Now, I want to build binary numbers with 6 digits. This equates to the number 63 in base 10:

```
val max_base10=63

val max_binary="%06d".format(max_base10.toBinaryString.toLong)
```

After that, I create a variable which will allow for column indexes to be permutated in ascending order:

```
def binary_permutationsSeg1 = for {a <- 1 to max_base10
} yield List(Array(0), %06d".format(a.toBinaryString.toLong).split("").map(_.toInt)) flatten // Array(0) is added as target is not an explanatory variable
```

This is just to make sure I get what I'm after:

```
binary_permutationsSeg1(62)
```

Now I wish to build my set of permutation models for which I MUST have an intercept.. I've learned the hard way that train() does not build an intercept in its algorithm...:

```
var regression = new LinearRegressionWithSGD().setIntercept(true)
regression.optimizer.setStepSize(0.1)
regression.optimizer.setNumIterations(100)
```

This bit is not very elegant as I create a double def... Also, I'd like to automatically create multiModel01, multiModel02 etc in memory but I'm not able to do it....

```
def multiModel = for{
a <- 1 to binary_permutationsSeg1.size-1
} yield df.rdd.map(r => LabeledPoint(
   r.getDouble(1),
Vectors.dense(binary_permutationsSeg1(a).zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == 1).unzip ._2 map(r.getDouble(_)) toArray))).cache()

def run_multiModel=for{
a <- 1 to binary_permutationsSeg1.size-1
} yield regression.run(multiModel(a))

run_multiModel
```

When I run the line above, I don't get the 62 models I am after which leaves me perplex.

These last two paragraphs are to do with model evaluation (taken from zero323 again) but I cannot make it so that it'd automatically contrust valuesAndPreds01, valuesAndPreds02 and so forth... whilst bearig in mind that some permutations will give NaN.

```
val valuesAndPreds = df.rdd.map { point =>
val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
(point.label, prediction)
}


val MSE = valuesAndPreds.map{case(v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2)}.mean()
println("training Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this problem and thanks for any suggestions or tips in the right direction.

Regards,

Christian

Comment: As always, it would be helpful if you could show what errors you are actually getting. Showing the types (by type annotation) of your various variables would also help the reader. Finally, something as complex as this really should have unit test cases (Specifications) so that we could see what works and what doesn't. As far as your run_multiModel method is concerned, I don't see how this compiles as your multiModel method does not take a parameter.