# Spark dataframe to LabeledPoint conversion

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to transform a Spark dataframe to a Labeled point RDD. I am using the following code, mostly inspired by a solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638770/rdd-to-labeledpoint-conversion). I can follow the logic of the code but unfortunately Sparks throws a "Task Not Serializable" error when I run this (more specificaly the part where I transform the RDD to Labelled Point)

```
val ignored = List("target")
val featInd = df.columns.diff(ignored).map(df.columns.indexOf(_))

// Get index of target
val targetInd = df.columns.indexOf("target") 

val labeled = df.rdd.map(r => LabeledPoint(
             r.getDouble(targetInd), // Get target value
             // Map feature indices to values
             Vectors.dense(featInd.map(r.getDouble(_)).toArray) 
))
```

When I try searching for this error, I realize that it's a generic error - However I am very new to Spark so have not really been able to figure out what's causing this error in this particular situation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Updating the error message:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:77)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:86)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:88)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:90)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:92)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:94)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:96)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:98)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:100)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:102)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:104)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC.(:106)   at $iwC.(:108)   at
>   (:110)     at .(:114)   at
>   .()  at .(:7)     at .()
>     at $print()    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:810)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:753)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:746)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: cast(unixtimestamp(x31,yyyy-mm-dd) as timestamp))
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: ts, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@21819ecc)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@55e507d9)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@73ab77c5)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@22ef6ab0)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6b8d0b8f)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5f2e0893)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@2859e1a9)
>     - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC, $iwC@2b85a09c)
>     - field (class: line2053277267$28.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
>     - object (class line2053277267$28.$read, line2053277267$28.$read@b3097a9)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL254, type: class line2053277267$28.$read)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7fb74a8a)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4c7d3fc3)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@59dc3f29)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@589580f9)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@3abf9e37)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@591c2bf7)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@27cdfbd6)
>     - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC, $iwC@53ed5332)
>     - field (class: line2053277267$56.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
>     - object (class line2053277267$56.$read, line2053277267$56.$read@376cb566)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name:
>   $VAL329, type: class line2053277267$56.$read)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC,
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6f9b0210)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC,
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@51f82ae2)
>     - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
>     - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
>     ... 51 more Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me the detailed error showed by console?

Comment: @UmbertoGriffo Just updated the question with the error that I encountered. Thanks!